# What does "supa doopa titus"mean in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> My answer is 7, is 7 the right answer?
> Absolutely Supa Doopa Titus! You win the prize.

These lines are from a Children's book called *Murderous Math* published by Scholastic. I just realized Titus is a name. This is one person speaking here.

What does "supa doopa titus"mean in the context?

Comment: _Super_ is a colloquial word for _very good_. _Super dooper_ is just a jokey way of emphasising it.

Comment: Titus is a male person's name, as the capital letter shows. 'Super-duper Titus!' means 'Congratulations, Titus!'.

Comment: You should always explain your context as clearly as you possibly can. Cite a source in your question rather than putting it in a comment later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supa Doopa is a spelling of "super-duper" which is just a childish way of saying "super". Super is a colloquial word for very good. Super dooper is just a jokey way of emphasising it.

Titus is a male person's name, as the capital letter shows. 'Super-duper Titus!' means 'Congratulations, Titus!'.

It seems to me that "Titus" says

> My answer is 7. Is 7 the right answer?

and a teacher (or similar) replies

> Absolutely super-duper, Titus! You win the prize!